# Calling method with argument in erb file Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have erb file with passing object post

```
<%= getTime(post) %>
```

And I have conroller for this erb file

```
helper_method :getTime

def getTime (post)

end
```

But controller doesn't see passed argument.

Comment: `doesn't see passed argument` - what does it mean?

Comment: What is the error message? Where is `post` variable you're passing defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getTime(post)
```

should be in a helper file.

Write this in application helper and it will be accesible in your view.

```
def getTime (post)

end
```

Comment: doesn't have to be a helper

Comment: I have to ask- do you have some extra information regarding this question? Where did you take the notification method from? Is it an answer for this question?

Comment: @BroiSatse The notification was just a more complex example of how he can render a partial as he was trying to do a similar task :) .

Comment: @pixelearth  Yeah you are right .. but mostly we don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the space between the method and the () in the def:

```
def getTime(post)
```

It probably is seeing the argument, since if it didn't it would throw an error saying you didn't supply it.

Whatever you're doing to "verify" that the argument is "seen" is probably not accurate.